# Zooming in Google Chrome using the mouse wheel? Not working

Tags: google-chrome, zoom

I know you can zoom in Google Chrome with CTRL + Mouse Scroll.
This works on my windows PC however not on my Mac.

I know that you can setup zoom feature on mac:

```
Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom > Use scroll gesture with keys to zoom
```

However this will not make the quality of what you are zooming in enhance. So I would prefer Google Chromes zoom scroll.

I can also do CMD + + however I want the scroll zoom.

**Someone know how to activate this feature or fix it?**

Comment: Did you try cmd + scroll ? At least in firefox, CMD + scroll using trackpad works

Comment: Not working too. I asked my friend and it works for him on his Mac. Is it an extensions or config file that I can reset for Chrome?

Comment: Since you said, you can do `ctrl` + `+` to  zoom, I think your modifier keys are a bit off  default. Check them in https://i.stack.imgur.com/rneqQ.png Also, check for App shortcuts while you're at it

Comment: Sry meant CMD. But thanks will look into that too